# Using the Exponential Response Formula to solve differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Exponential Response Formula (ERF) states that for any differential equation $$P(D)y = e^{rt}$$ (where $P$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, $D$ is a differential operator, and $r$ is a real or complex number), then if $P(r) \neq 0$, a particular solution to the differential equation is given by $$y_{p} = \frac{e^{rt}}{P(r)}$$
I am tasked with solving the following differential equation: $$(D^3+D+3)x=\cos(2t)$$I only have $\cos(2t)$, the real part of $e^{2it}$, so is it safe to assume that the solution would be $$Re\left[\frac{e^{2it}}{P(2i)}\right]?$$
Following this logic, the solution would be $$ Re\left[\frac{\cos(2t) +i\sin(2t)}{-6i+3}\right].$$
Multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate:
$$\frac{\cos(2t) +i\sin(2t)}{-6i+3}\cdot\frac{-6i-3}{-6i-3}$$
results in $$\frac{-6i\cos(2t) +6\sin(2t)+3\cos(2t)+3i\sin(2t)}{-45}$$
Therefore, taking the real part of the above expression equals $$Re\left[\frac{-6i\cos(2t) +6\sin(2t)+3\cos(2t)+3i\sin(2t)}{-45}\right]$$
which is simply $$\boxed{-\frac{2\sin(2t)+cos(2t)}{15}}$$
Is my solution correct? Please also leave any concerns about my writing, as I am knew to MSE and to writing in MathJax

Comment: shouldnt it be $P(2i)=-6i+3$ ??

Comment: @Isham Yes Thank You! I'll fix that right away!

Comment: +1 Check if you get the same answer as mine..apart from that sign mistake You did a good job...

Comment: ...write more simply $$\frac{\cos(2t) +i\sin(2t)}{-6i+3}*\frac{6i+3}{6i+3}$$ you avoid making sign mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $P(2i)=-6i+3$

$$\frac{\cos(2t) +i\sin(2t)}{-6i+3}*\frac{-6i-3}{-6i-3}$$
Or more simply
$$\frac{\cos(2t) +i\sin(2t)}{-6i+3}*\frac{6i+3}{6i+3}$$
This results in
$$\frac{6i\cos(2t) -6\sin(2t)+3\cos(2t)+3i\sin(2t)}{45}$$
And finally
$$x_p= \frac {\cos(2t)-2\sin(2t)}{15}$$

---

Another method

$$(D^3+D+3)x=\cos(2t)$$
$$\implies x_p=\frac 1{(D^3+D+3)}\cos(2t)$$
$$ 3x_p=\frac 1{(1-D)}\cos(2t)$$
$$ 3x_p=\frac {1+D}{(1-D^2)}\cos(2t)$$
$$ 15x_p= ({1+D})\cos(2t)$$
$$ 15x_p= \cos(2t)-2\sin(2t)$$

Can you check the value of the polynomial ? it should be if I am not wrong $-6i+3$

Comment: how are you going from the 2nd to the third line and from the 4th to the 5th? I imagine both moves are similar, but it is not obvious to me.

Comment: @RaxAdaam first method or second one ?

Comment: if it's in the second method (second line to third line)  then you have to know that $D^2$ can be evaluated when acting on $\cos(at)$ as $-a^2$. I have $D^3$ but $D^3=D(D^2)=D(-4)$ then i simplified expression with D I already had $-4D+D=-3D$ and put the factor 3 at the numeroator on the right side for simplicity. @RaxAdaam I hope it's more clear ?

Comment: @RaxAdaam for the second question ( 3 to 4 line ?) I just multiplied numerator and denominator by $D+1$ So I can have a $D^2$ at the numerator and simplify the denominator. With the same method I already explained in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable to assume that the solution will be of the form $x(t) = a_1 + a_2cos(2t) + a_3sin(2t)$, where $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants to be determined.

Let's find the derivatives of $x(t)$:

- $Dx(t) = -2a_2sin(2t) + 2a_3cos(2t)$
- $D^2x(t) = -4a_2cos(2t) -4a_3sin(2t)$
- $D^3x(t) = 8a_2sin(2t) - 8a_3cos(2t)$

Let's plug the above into your differential equation $(D^3 + D + 3)x(t) = cos(2t)$, implying:

$8a_2sin(2t)-8a_3cos(2t)-2a_2sin(2t)+2a_3cos(2t)+3a_1+3a_2cos(2t)+3a_3sin(2t)=cos(2t)$.

Combining terms, we get:

$(3a_2-6a_3)cos(2t) + (6a_2+3a_3)sin(2t) + 3a_1 = cos(2t)$.

This yields:

$3a_2-6a_3=1, \; 6a_2+3a_3=0, \; a_1=0$. You can solve the equations to get $a_2 = 1/15$ and $a_3 = -2/15$.

Thus, $x(t) = \frac{1}{15}cos(2t) - \frac{2}{15}sin(2t)$.